# Native hadoop library assembly

Tags: java, c++, hadoop, mapreduce

How to collect own hadoop library according to http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.18.3/native_libraries.html#Building+Native+Hadoop+Libraries (I not all understood, for example, I have no folder build/native assembly and  own and that in a command $ant -Dcompile.native=true  what is target)?

Answer (score 0):

The build/native folder will be created after you execute the ant script.

If you don't provide a specific target, the default target is compile (if you look in the build.xml file in the root of your hadoop directory)